# How to make RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory?

Tags: android, error-handling, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-android

I found [this](http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html).

But in new ver `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'` at CallAdapter it has two params
`CallAdapter<?,?>`

How to modify [RxCallAdapterWrapper](http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html) to `implement` if from `CallAdapter<?,?>`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of the blog post you referenced*

The original post was meant as a proof of concept and for RxJava 2 so it's easier for me to explain with that version too, but I'll try and cover more ground. I'm guessing you're using version 1, since you talk about `adapter-rxjava` and not `adapter-rxjava2`. That said, the implementation for version 1 should be pretty straight forward and just a matter of using the right imports.

Here's what I've done using RxJava 2:

```
class RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory extends CallAdapter.Factory {
  private final RxJava2CallAdapterFactory original;

  private RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory() {
    original = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create();
  }

  public static CallAdapter.Factory create() {
    return new RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory();
  }

  @Override
  public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
    return new RxCallAdapterWrapper(retrofit, original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit));
  }

  private static class RxCallAdapterWrapper<R> implements CallAdapter<R, Object> {
    private final Retrofit retrofit;
    private final CallAdapter<R, Object> wrapped;

    public RxCallAdapterWrapper(Retrofit retrofit, CallAdapter<R, Object> wrapped) {
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Type responseType() {
        return wrapped.responseType();
    }

    @Override
    public Object adapt(Call<R> call) {
        Object result = wrapped.adapt(call);
        if (result instanceof Single) {
            return ((Single) result).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, SingleSource>() {
                @Override
                public SingleSource apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    return Single.error(asRetrofitException(throwable));
                }
            });
        }
        if (result instanceof Observable) {
            return ((Observable) result).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableSource apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    return Observable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable));
                }
            });
        }

        if (result instanceof Completable) {
            return ((Completable) result).onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, CompletableSource>() {
                @Override
                public CompletableSource apply(@NonNull Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    return Completable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable));
                }
            });
        }

        return result;
    }

    private RetrofitException asRetrofitException(Throwable throwable) {
        // We had non-200 http error
        if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
            HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;
            Response response = httpException.response();
            return RetrofitException.httpError(response.raw().request().url().toString(), response, retrofit);
        }
        // A network error happened
        if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
            return RetrofitException.networkError((IOException) throwable);
        }

        // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error

        return RetrofitException.unexpectedError(throwable);
    }
  }
}
```

No major changes, just some playing around with return types. Now if you look at the `RxJava2CallAdapter` it implements `CallAdapter<R, Object>`, so we need to account for this.

Then I've added some checks for the instance types to make sure we're returning the right things.

The really important part is to make sure you import the right packages. Retrofit adapters check for specific classes. One problem I had was having the wrong imports and had situations where I was checking if the `Throwable` was an instance of `com.jakewharton.retrofit2.adapter.HttpException`, while it was actually an instance of `retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.HttpException`.

Hope this helps

Comment: so `CallAdapter<?, ?>` can not by applied for rxjava 1.x, right?

Comment: As far as I see here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-adapters/rxjava/src/main/java/retrofit2/adapter/rxjava/RxJavaCallAdapter.java - The call adapter for rxjava 1.x also implements ``CallAdapter<?, ?>``, that's why I presume it's fairly easy to change the code I have here to use the classes from RxJava 1.x

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for the answer and keeping on top of stuff like this. I receive an unchecked warning on return new RxCallAdapterWrapper(...) Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: If it's a warning it's usually because of generics and in this case should be fine.

Answer (score 8):

Updated [anwer of Fred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252881/2425851) to `kotlin` style and

**rxjava1:**

`com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.5.0` with `io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8`

**RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.kt**

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.CallAdapter
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory
import rx.Observable
import java.io.IOException
import java.lang.reflect.Type

/**
 * Created by Nikolay Unuchek on 28.11.2016.
 */

internal class RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory private constructor() : CallAdapter.Factory() {
    private val original: RxJavaCallAdapterFactory = RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create()

    override fun get(returnType: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        return RxCallAdapterWrapper(retrofit, original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit) ?: return null)
    }

    private class RxCallAdapterWrapper<R>(
        private val retrofit: Retrofit,
        private val wrapped: CallAdapter<R, *>
    ) : CallAdapter<R, Any> {

        override fun responseType(): Type {
            return wrapped.responseType()
        }

        override fun adapt(call: Call<R>): Any {
            val result = wrapped.adapt(call)
            if (result is Observable<*>) {
                return result.onErrorResumeNext { throwable -> Observable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable as Throwable)) }
            }

            return result
        }

        private fun asRetrofitException(throwable: Throwable): RetrofitException {
            // We had non-200 http error
            if (throwable is HttpException) {
                val response = throwable.response()
                return RetrofitException.httpError(response.raw().request.url.toString(), response, throwable)
            }
            // A network error happened
            return if (throwable is IOException) {
                RetrofitException.networkError(throwable)
            } else RetrofitException.unexpectedError(throwable)

            // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error

        }
    }

    companion object {

        fun create(): CallAdapter.Factory {
            return RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory()
        }
    }
}
```

**RetrofitException.kt**

```
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.Response
import java.io.IOException
class RetrofitException
private constructor(
    message: String?,
    /**
     * The request URL which produced the error.
     */
    val url: String?,
    /**
     * Response object containing status code, headers, body, etc.
     */
    val response: Response<*>?,
    /**
     * The event kind which triggered this error.
     */
    val kind: Kind,
    exception: Throwable
) : RuntimeException(message, exception) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return super.toString() + " : " + kind + " : " + url + " : " + response?.errorBody()?.string()
    }

    /**
     * Identifies the event kind which triggered a [RetrofitException].
     */
    enum class Kind {
        /**
         * An [IOException] occurred while communicating to the server.
         */
        NETWORK,
        /**
         * A non-200 HTTP status code was received from the server.
         */
        HTTP,
        /**
         * An internal error occurred while attempting to execute a request. It is best practice to
         * re-throw this exception so your application crashes.
         */
        UNEXPECTED
    }

    companion object {
        fun httpError(url: String, response: Response<*>, httpException: HttpException): RetrofitException {
            val message = response.code().toString() + " " + response.message()
            return RetrofitException(message, url, response, Kind.HTTP, httpException)
        }

        fun networkError(exception: IOException): RetrofitException {
            return RetrofitException(exception.message, null, null, Kind.NETWORK, exception)
        }

        fun unexpectedError(exception: Throwable): RetrofitException {
            return RetrofitException(exception.message, null, null, Kind.UNEXPECTED, exception)
        }

        fun asRetrofitException(throwable: Throwable): RetrofitException {
            if (throwable is RetrofitException) {
                return throwable
            }
            // We had non-200 http error
            if (throwable is HttpException) {
                val response = throwable.response()
                return httpError(response.raw().request().url().toString(), response, throwable)
            }
            // A network error happened
            return if (throwable is IOException) {
                networkError(throwable)
            } else unexpectedError(throwable)
            // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error
        }
    }
}
```

**rxjava2:**

`com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.6.0` with `io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9`

**RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.kt**

```
import by.gramophone.api.errorhandling.RetrofitException.Companion.asRetrofitException
import io.reactivex.Completable
import io.reactivex.Observable
import io.reactivex.Single
import io.reactivex.functions.Function
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.CallAdapter
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.RxJava2CallAdapterFactory
import java.lang.reflect.Type



/**
 * Created by Nikolay Unuchek on 28.11.2016.
 */

internal class RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory private constructor() : CallAdapter.Factory() {
    private val original = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()

    override fun get(returnType: Type, annotations: Array<Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): CallAdapter<*, *>? {
        return RxCallAdapterWrapper(original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit) ?: return null)
    }

    private class RxCallAdapterWrapper<R>(private val wrapped: CallAdapter<R, *>) : CallAdapter<R, Any> {

        override fun responseType(): Type {
            return wrapped.responseType()
        }

        override fun adapt(call: Call<R>): Any {
            return when (val result = wrapped.adapt(call)) {
                is Single<*> -> result.onErrorResumeNext(Function { throwable -> Single.error(asRetrofitException(throwable)) })
                is Observable<*> -> result.onErrorResumeNext(Function { throwable -> Observable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable)) })
                is Completable -> result.onErrorResumeNext (Function{ throwable -> Completable.error(asRetrofitException(throwable)) } )
                else -> result
            }

        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(): CallAdapter.Factory {
            return RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory()
        }
    }
}
```

**RetrofitException.kt**

```
import retrofit2.HttpException
import retrofit2.Response
import java.io.IOException
class RetrofitException
private constructor(
    message: String?,
    /**
     * The request URL which produced the error.
     */
    val url: String?,
    /**
     * Response object containing status code, headers, body, etc.
     */
    val response: Response<*>?,
    /**
     * The event kind which triggered this error.
     */
    val kind: Kind,
    exception: Throwable
) : RuntimeException(message, exception) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return super.toString() + " : " + kind + " : " + url + " : " + response?.errorBody()?.string()
    }

    /**
     * Identifies the event kind which triggered a [RetrofitException].
     */
    enum class Kind {
        /**
         * An [IOException] occurred while communicating to the server.
         */
        NETWORK,
        /**
         * A non-200 HTTP status code was received from the server.
         */
        HTTP,
        /**
         * An internal error occurred while attempting to execute a request. It is best practice to
         * re-throw this exception so your application crashes.
         */
        UNEXPECTED
    }

    companion object {
        fun httpError(url: String, response: Response<*>, httpException: HttpException): RetrofitException {
            val message = response.code().toString() + " " + response.message()
            return RetrofitException(message, url, response, Kind.HTTP, httpException)
        }

        fun networkError(exception: IOException): RetrofitException {
            return RetrofitException(exception.message, null, null, Kind.NETWORK, exception)
        }

        fun unexpectedError(exception: Throwable): RetrofitException {
            return RetrofitException(exception.message, null, null, Kind.UNEXPECTED, exception)
        }

        fun asRetrofitException(throwable: Throwable): RetrofitException {
            if (throwable is RetrofitException) {
                return throwable
            }
            // We had non-200 http error
            if (throwable is HttpException) {
                val response = throwable.response()
                return httpError(response.raw().request().url().toString(), response, throwable)
            }
            // A network error happened
            return if (throwable is IOException) {
                networkError(throwable)
            } else unexpectedError(throwable)
            // We don't know what happened. We need to simply convert to an unknown error
        }
    }
}
```