# Trouble call fails with Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.reflect.Type retrofit2.CallAdapter.responseType()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I'm having trouble doing a retrofit request that returns a simple Call object.

I have my retrofit setup done this way:

```
 new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));
```

And I have the following retrofit interface which has mixed rxjava and simple calls defined

```
MyInterface {
   Single getSingle1();
   Single getSingle2();
   Call getCall1();
}
```

The issue that I face is when I execute:
`myInterface.getCall1().execute()` I get the following error

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.reflect.Type retrofit2.CallAdapter.responseType()' on a null object reference
```

Should be noted that if I convert `Call getCall1()` to return `Completable getCall1()` everything works as expected.

Anyone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming `RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory` is the class mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43252881/12125691).

Implementations of `CallAdapterFactory` should return `null` for a type it doesn't know how to adapt.  The wrapped `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` does this correctly, and returns null for Call return types (which are normally handled by the built-in `DefaultCallAdapterFactory`).  However, `RxErrorHandlingCallAdapterFactory` will happily ignore this and return an adapter that delegates to null, causing a crash when you actually try to get a `Call`.

To correctly indicate calls it can't handle, your CallAdapterFactory should return null whenever the wrapped factory returns null:

```
  public CallAdapter<?, ?> get(Type returnType, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
      CallAdapter wrapped = original.get(returnType, annotations, retrofit);
      if (wrapped = null) {
          return null;
      }

      return new RxCallAdapterWrapper(retrofit, wrapped);
  }
```